# Mouse becomes unusable after Corsair Headset

Tags: 14.04, usb, sound, mouse, bluetooth

I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS (You can view the system details [here](http://pastebin.com/czsBtg9a)) on my PC and have recently experienced an apparent common fault - when turning on the Corsair Void Headset, my mouse becomes unusable (as in, clicking links has no effect).

Here is the result of a `lshw` for the Void Headset (mouse and keyboard):

```
          *-usb:0
               description: Human interface device
               product: Corsair VOID RGB Wireless Gaming Headset
               vendor: Corsair
               physical id: 2
               bus info: usb@3:2
               version: 0.00
               capabilities: usb-1.10
               configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
          *-usb:1
               description: Mouse
               product: Corsair Gaming Scimitar RGB Mouse
               vendor: Corsair
               physical id: 3
               bus info: usb@3:3
               version: 2.03
               serial: 15032016AEAA1003550F1E8AF5001942
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=300mA speed=12Mbit/s
         *-usb:3
               description: Keyboard
               product: Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard
               vendor: Corsair
               physical id: 9
               bus info: usb@3:9
               version: 2.04
               serial: 1300C019AE3D8C805397BBE7F5001947
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

For the actual USB controller, I can provide the following:

```
         *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:f7a1a000-f7a1a3ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-22-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Intel Corp.
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@2:1
               version: 0.00
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
```

Full hardware list can be located [here](http://pastebin.com/6MTBkuDm). I had a [quick look at this post](http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=153831) and could see a gentlemen suggest the following:

`lsusb` to obtain the information on the USB dongle

Then `nano` the following line:

`options usbhid quirks=0x1b1c:0x1b27:0x0004"` (Where the ID's matched your USB)

Save to `/etc/modprobe.d/` calling it `usbhid.conf` and lastly run `"mkinitcpio -p linux"` however `mkiniticpio` is not installed on Ubunut (if this is even a package to install, I've just started reading about it).

My only current solution would be to not need to turn the headset on (i.e. not need to press the power button to enable) as I believe this is where the fault is.

I'll keep digging and update this question, but any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this same problem, this is the workaround I've made till there is a real fix.

make corsairFix.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
corsairId=$(xinput --list | grep "Corsair Corsair VOID Wireless Gaming Dongle" | grep -oP '(?<=id=)\d*')
if [ -z "$corsairId" ]; then
  echo "Corsair VOID Dongle was not found!"
else
  xinput set-int-prop $corsairId "Device Enabled" 8 0
fi
```

then run:

```
$ sleep 20 && ./corsairFix.sh
```

Then quickly add the usb dongle and your mouse and keyboard should be fixed when it runs. This will also disable the on headset volume buttons (not that they work right now anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, even if http://www.c0urier.net/2016/corsair-gaming-void-usb-rgb-linux-fun didn't work for me on Linux Mint KDE 18, your script (after also running "chmod +x corsairFix.sh") works perfectly!